# Spring SAML integration with WSO2 Identity server, SAML Message ID not reconised

Tags: spring-security, wso2, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have taken the Spring SAML example (see section 4.2 [in this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html)) which works with the Open source login page SSO, and tried to add support to use WSO2 Identity Server as an additional IDP service.
To do this I changed the spring SAML sample project by adding a metadata xml file for IS, and added an entry for the IS metadata to the securityContext.xml.

On running the spring application I now get presented with an option to login using IS, and I can successfully login in on WSO2 when I'm redirected to it. However the spring application throws an exception on the IS SAML response about it not matching the InResponseToField.

```
2015-01-05 09:54:12,845 line="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger.log(SAMLDefaultLogger.java:127)" thread="http-nio-8080-exec-4" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger" AuthNResponse;FAILURE;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;com:vdenotaris:spring:sp;localhost;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message ae2dab0fb8b0g8e49971b91a73e91i
```

From debugging the application it appears the response message is not recognised as belonging to the same session as the request message. I say that from these 2 log messages, 1st is logged when sending the AuthRequest and the 2nd is when the response is received:

```
2015-01-05 09:53:20,867 line="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage.storeMessage(HttpSessionStorage.java:93)" thread="http-nio-8080-exec-1" class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage" Storing message ae2dab0fb8b0g8e49971b91a73e91i to session 26D3B7D9E33F26A7A5092BF6909B9D13
...
2015-01-05 09:54:10,731 line="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage.retrieveMessage(HttpSessionStorage.java:117)" thread="http-nio-8080-exec-4" class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage" Message ae2dab0fb8b0g8e49971b91a73e91i not found in session BBF256F284F55D774E6997600E9B3388
```

The IS SAML response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO" ID="adlbklpnldoanfphalcaahhacooinnldcejjjioe" InResponseTo="ae2dab0fb8b0g8e49971b91a73e91i" IssueInstant="2015-01-05T09:53:38.063Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
   <saml2p:Status>
      <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
   </saml2p:Status>
   <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ebhfkdhlgbhclcklefjigfddoikklhjlanlbolel" IssueInstant="2015-01-05T09:53:38.065Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
      <saml2:Subject>
         <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">smit005</saml2:NameID>
     <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ae2dab0fb8b0g8e49971b91a73e91i" NotOnOrAfter="2015-01-05T09:58:38.063Z" Recipient="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO"/>
     </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml2:Subject>
  <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2015-01-05T09:53:38.065Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-01-05T09:58:38.063Z">
     <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml2:Audience>com:vdenotaris:spring:sp</saml2:Audience>
     </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml2:Conditions>
  <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-01-05T09:53:38.068Z" SessionIndex="406d4530-6fcf-4edf-b876-a68de4b4ea79">
     <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
     </saml2:AuthnContext>
  </saml2:AuthnStatement>
  <saml2:AttributeStatement/>
   </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

For reference I attach the metadata xml file I added for WSO2 IS (I had to give it an entityID of 'localhost' as this was what WSO2 IS insists on returning (it uses the host name by default)).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
                     entityID="localhost"
                     validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z">
   <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" >
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE
                    CAwCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxDTALBgNVBAoMBFdTTzIxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWxv
                    Y2FsaG9zdDAeFw0xMDAyMTkwNzAyMjZaFw0zNTAyMTMwNzAyMjZaMFUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQsw
                    CQYDVQQIDAJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzENMAsGA1UECgwEV1NPMjESMBAGA1UE
                    AwwJbG9jYWxob3N0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUp/oV1vWc8/TkQSiAvTou
                    sMzOM4asB2iltr2QKozni5aVFu818MpOLZIr8LMnTzWllJvvaA5RAAdpbECb+48FjbBe0hseUdN5
                    HpwvnH/DW8ZccGvk53I6Orq7hLCv1ZHtuOCokghz/ATrhyPq+QktMfXnRS4HrKGJTzxaCcU7OQID
                    AQABoxIwEDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBPAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAW5wPR7cr1LAdq+IrR44i
                    QlRG5ITCZXY9hI0PygLP2rHANh+PYfTmxbuOnykNGyhM6FjFLbW2uZHQTY1jMrPprjOrmyK5sjJR
                    O4d1DeGHT/YnIjs9JogRKv4XHECwLtIVdAbIdWHEtVZJyMSktcyysFcvuhPQK8Qc/E/Wq8uHSCo=</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
       <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
       <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
       <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
       <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
   </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

As requested I've saved a log of the browser HTTP messages on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eawt3f4y5wqehr1/localhost.har?dl=0).

Comment: Can you include dump of HTTP messages going through your browser during the single sign-on process?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I've added a link to a log of the browser messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both Spring SAML and your IDP WSO2 server are deployed on the same domain - *localhost*. This is what happens:

- Spring SAML creates an HTTP session (*JSESSIONID* - `82F3ECD1A1E4F9B7DB0134F3129267A5`) and initializes single sign-on
- WSO2 accepts the request and authenticates the user, but creates its own session (JSESSIONID -`C34B21931C53080487B5B9BA6EB490D2`) and redirects user back to Spring SAML
- container running Spring SAML receives the cookie with *JSESSIONID* (`C34B21931C53080487B5B9BA6EB490D2`), but as it doesn't recognize such session it creates a new one (`E712A8422009613F6FD3901327690726`)
- Spring SAML tries to verify received SAML message based on the original request, but it cannot be found because the original session is now gone

The easiest way to fix this is to change session cookie name for Spring SAML or WSO2. You could also deploy your applications on different domains (for example by giving your localhost an alias in the hosts file - `/etc/hosts` or `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

Comment: This was indeed the problem, in the end I set up wso2 to run in a VM. This was easier than getting it to use another domain.

Comment: @vladimír-schäfer, how do we manage to change the session cookie name for Spring SAML?

Comment: As part of Spring Security - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964921/custom-cookie-name-when-using-spring-session