# java spring session how to custom cookie key

Tags: spring, session, cookies, redis

I using [spring session HttpSession](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-xml.html), how can I custom cookie key, I tried this solution: [Custom cookie name when using Spring Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964921/custom-cookie-name-when-using-spring-session). but it does not work, the name is SESSION still.

my config like below:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/env/env_test.properties"/> 
<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
     p:port="${spring.redis.port}" p:hostName="${spring.redis.host}"/>
<bean id="mapSessionRepository" class="org.springframework.session.MapSessionRepository" />
<bean id="sessionRepositoryFilter"             
  class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter">
  <constructor-arg ref="sessionRepository"/>
  <property name="httpSessionStrategy">
    <bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy">
      <property name="cookieName" value="_session_id" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below `bean` to create `custom cookie`.

```
    <bean class ="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
            <property name="cookieName" value="JSESIONID"></property>       
    </bean>

JESSIONID - Custom Cookie Name

    Please remove below configuration fr`enter code here`om xml file.

    <bean id="sessionRepositoryFilter"             
      class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter">
      <constructor-arg ref="sessionRepository"/>
      <property name="httpSessionStrategy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy">
          <property name="cookieName" value="_session_id" />
        </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a bean with class

```
org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer
```

So inside of that bean, you define your custom properties, after you declare that bean as a property of the following:

```
org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy
```

By example:

```
<bean id="yourCookieSerializer" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
        <property name="cookieName" value="yourCustomName"/>
        <property name="cookiePath" value="yourCustomPath"/>
        ...
</bean>
<bean id="cookieHttpSessionStrategy" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy">
        <property name="cookieSerializer" ref="yourCookieSerializer"></property>
</bean>
```